# multiple profiles on same machine with different regions

Tags: psn

I have 2 profiles on the same ps4 machine a us and a uk one while I am aware that dlc is region locked, can I get one psn plus subscription and all regions will play online multiplayer? And is it better to keep the uk or the us as primary? I see the us are cheaper
Thank you

Comment: the second part of your question *"is it better to keep the uk or the us as primary"* is opinion based since it'll also depend on where you live and what sites you have access to. i Live in Australia and i would choose UK over US as i can't get US PSN Cards as easily as i can with UK PSN Cards (US Cards i play up to +75% more on the actual value of the card), ofcause my main account is Australian and UK and Aus DLC are interchangeable on the PS3 and PS4 (brought Child of Light from the UK as a download code, downloaded it and DLC with my Aus account), only the Vita screw things up

Answer (score 1):

Your PSN Plus subscription and its benefits are only relevant to the account it is associated with. Any other account will only benefit from the subscription in that you can play the games licensed to the device. Online multi-player that requires a Plus membership is not accessible to the other accounts.

Technically, it's not what **account** is primary for the device. It's more a case of which **device** is primary to the account.

Personally, if you have a choice between the two, I'd say look at which one has the best free download offerings and go with that one. You can always subscribe to both as well.

Comment: Online multiplayer is accessible to all users in the primary system regardless of region.